# Epsa crop broken after deploy via features

Tags: 7, features

I have a local Drupal installation with [Epsa Image Crop](https://drupal.org/project/epsacrop). Everything works perfect and out of the box. I created a feature with the image crops and then things went wrong...

When I try to apply an image crop locally, I following picture. Like it should.
[image]

However, on the remote site I get this:
[image]

As you can see, the dimensions of the highlighted area are correct, but for some reason, the dialog box isn't taking the image on it's full width...

I already applied [this patch](https://drupal.org/node/1396500#comment-8017865), but no luck here... Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Hi, I'm the developer of EPSA Crop, and what I can tell you that it looks like that you have a Javascript error, can you please check the console log? I guess the issue might be relevant for you: https://drupal.org/node/793142

Comment: Hi @yvan, thank you so much for your feedback. However, I don't get any errors in my console... Locally it works just fine, but remotely, every single crop is broken.

Comment: Is it possible for you to pastebin.com an export of your styles ?

Comment: Sure, here you go! http://pastebin.com/hRwThS6X Thx for the help!

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, but right now I don't have a clue why it happens. I'm trying to replicate it in my local and dev server (aswissidea) but nothing like you get.